# how to create path os independent?

Tags: erlang

I want to create `tmp` directory under the `priv` directory independent of os.

In the following code, I have to add "/" here， but it break the condition of os independent.

```
get_tmp_path()->
    A = filename:join(get_priv_path(),"tmp"),   
    filelib:ensure_dir(A ++ "/"),  %%<---------- I have to add "/" here， but it break the condition of os independent
    A.
```

How to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`filelib:ensure_dir("../test/test1").` works perfectly in windows environment. Same thing with absolute path:

```
1> Home = "D:/documents and Settings/test".
"D:/documents and Settings/test"
2> filelib:ensure_dir(Home ++ "/test1").       
ok
3>
```

and I do not expect problem in linux environment.